# setVisible and requestFocus on textField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I have action thread and since it is Swing software, EDT. 
I want my program to draw dialog window, and when it appears and it's filled with data, I want to get focus on selected text field. 

**Code flow**: When I execute, it will run main thread, which calls method to draw dialog in invokeLater on EDT. Then program proceeds and in main thread it calls next methods that are being run in ED thread, again using invokeLater.

**Problem**: When I run it normally, it will not get focus on my text field.

**Observation**: But when I add some sleep (300 milis) to main thread, introducing time gap between one invokeLater call and next call in EDT, *it works just like I want*.

It seems to me like two actions added to AWT queue must be separated by some time, otherwise the second one doesn't work. I mean here setVisible(true) on dialog, and then requestFocus() on textField. Maybe requestFocus() only work when it sees dialog window drawn?

**Question**:How can I make things work, some synchronization method, maybe checking on dialog before calling requestFocus() (may be hard, because its in other class).

**Solution**:I forgot about most important thing - after calling setVisible() next thing I do is call to setEnabled(false) so user cannot do anything before data filling is completed. The problem was there, in setEnabled() I also was adding tasks to AWT queue (by invokeLater()). This task caused corruption of next steps. What I do now to fix it is calling this setEnabled(false) from my main thread inside invokeAndWait(). If I understand it correctly, now the dialog popup section is called first, and then main thread waits until EDT proceed his work and then setEnabled(false) is called. So technically user is not enabled to do anything after the window is drawn, which makes sense for me. 
 
Anyway thanks for your responses.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Comment: It's not much more than i posted here. I can paste code that looks like "invokeLater -> run() -> setVisible(true)" because there is a lot of code doing other things not connected with problem

Comment: Tip: Avoid using wall of text, if we can't understand, we can't answer.

Comment: Thanks for tip and edit

Comment: Add an `AncestorListener` as described in [Dialog Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/).

Comment: @vul6: Try not to use [requestFocus()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus-boolean-) as stated in the API, this method's behaviour is platform dependent, instead try the other alternative, as stated _requestFocusInWindow__

Comment: Also make sure that the component can request focus (`.setFocusable()`). I'm pretty sure this should be enabled by default, but it may not be.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html

Answer (score 3):

It's better to call the focus setting from the dialog. Add a `WindowListener` to the dialog and use either

```
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e)
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e);
```

to set focus on the `JTextField` instance

Comment: Where should I add this? In invokeLater for dialog draw, or somewhere in textField method?

Comment: @vul6 to Top-level container, have to bothering with official Oracle tutorial How to use WindowListener

Answer (score 1):

The `requestFocusInWindow()` method can only be invoked on a visible component. That means the frame/dialog must already be visible when you invoke the method.

If you are trying to do this on a modal dialog you may have problems. Check out `Dialog Focus` for a simple listener you can use to set focus on a component.

Comment: The problem was that I havent call this functions and objects from one class, but from separate ones. Task scheduling on AWT simply sometimes works wrong I think.